# Touch moviment in godot

Tags: mobile, godot, 2d-games, topdown

I'm not able with any youtube tutorial and blogs to make a joystick movement for my topdown 2d game on godot

as I said, follow step by step several tutorials on the internet / youtube and I couldn't get my joystick for my topdown2d game

Answer (score 0):

You should not need any special code to use a joystick with Godot. Run of the mill code like this should work:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var speed := 500.0

func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    var velocity := Vector2(
        Input.get_axis("left", "right"),
        Input.get_axis("forward", "backward")
    ) * speed
    move_and_slide(velocity)
```

Either that or something similar you might find in most tutorials. Which probably use "ui_left", "ui_right", "ui_up" and "ui_down" which are pre-defined actions. And yes, there are also pre-defined joystick inputs for those actions, but they might not be correct for your device.

---

Before configuring the actions, make sure the device is recognized by the operating system (you might need to install/update drivers). *You might also want to run a diagnostic tool to check if it can send input.*

Now, configure the actions on Project Settings -> Input Map. You can add new actions or modify the pre-existing ones. Once you have the action defined, click on the "+" icon on the right, and there you will find the "Joy Button" and "Joy Axis" options which will let you configure the joystick input for the action. *Double click will allow you to modify the existing ones.*

*There is always the chance you configured the wrong input on the wrong action. You could figure it out by trial an error or with the help of a diagnostic tool.*

If your device works, the configuration is correct and it still does not work. We could be talking of a compatibility issue. *You might want to [report a bug on github](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues).*

*I can't help you further without knowing what did you try and the results you got.*